# Where is this margin/padding coming from?

Tags: css

I have been scratching my head over this for a while. Where is the bottom line of purple below the image coming from on this page:
http://www.office-answers.co.uk/reviews/

I see nothing in inspect element which looks to give any extra size to the containing element, and it's doing my head in!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Always include the relevant code in the question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks Roope, but having no clue as to the relevant code that was going to be difficult. Luckily answers which fix the problem have come in.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The default display type of an image is `inline` or `inline-block` using HTML. The extra space is there to take into account the descenders at the bottom of letters (like in y or q) that may be on the same line.

There's two ways to get rid of the text. You can either use `display: block`, or you can use `vertical-align: top`. The vertical align way just pushes the non-existent descenders back up, removing the space, while displaying it as a block makes it behave as a block level element - and you don't get plain text set that way, hence no descenders.

Comment: That works, which works for me in this instance. Not meant to be spending any time on 'design' with this site, so the quick fix to remove the extra is great. Thanks.

Comment: @JasonDilworth I updated my post to explain why it happens, and the different ways to resolve it. Glad I could help!

Answer (score -1):

Seems to be your `line-height`.

Either set it to zero, or make the image a block element.